# In a list - how can I call a method in the base only once

Tags: c#, oop

I want to call a method only once from the base class in a list of classes that all of them derived from base, how can I call method in the base class only once?

```
public class Base
{
    public virtual void foo()
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("Base foo()");
    }
}
public class A : Base
{
    public override void foo()
    {
        base.foo();
        Debug.WriteLine("A foo()");
    }
}
public class B : Base
{
    public override void foo()
    {
        base.foo();
        Debug.WriteLine("B foo()");
    }
}
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<Base> list = new List<Base>();
        list.Add(new A());
        list.Add(new B());
        list.Add(new A());
        foreach (Base item in list)
        {
            item.foo();
        }
    }
}
```

instead of :

```
Base foo()
A foo()
Base foo()
B foo()
Base foo()
A foo()
```

I want the following result:

```
Base foo()
A foo()
B foo()
A foo()
```

Comment: It's possible to achieve, but the question is why? What's wrong with displaying `Base foo()` for each `base()` call? Or shall I ask why do you want to see that `Base foo()` once at all? You can implement "is-initialized pattern" to avoid duplicated call (if base call is expensive) but in given context it's not clear why, the example is too abstract.

Comment: Thanks, my website uses different roles for the same user, user can have multiple roles - all of them inherits from the same baseuser. In the base user I bind the controls - and once is enough

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a static flag in the base, and adjust the flag

```
public class Base
{
    public Base()
    {
        if (_instance == null)
            _instance = this;//record the first instance
    }
    static Base _instance;
    public virtual void foo()
    {
        if (_instance == this)
            Debug.WriteLine("Base foo()");
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks, nice solution - but it was easier fror me to implement following Igor's solution.

Answer (score 2):

Seems like a nonsensical requirement that breaks SoS. To answer your question though you would need a static member boolean in the base class that is flagged as soon as the base method is called.

```
public class Base
{
    // is not thread safe
    protected static bool isFooCalled;

    public virtual void foo()
    {
        if(isFooCalled)
            return;
        Debug.WriteLine("Base foo()");
        isFooCalled = true;
    }
    public static void Reset()
    {
        isFooCalled = false;
    }
}
```

If you do not even want the method to be entered you would have to add the check in each derived class as well.

```
public class A : Base
{
    public override void foo()
    {
        if(!Base.isFooCalled)
            base.foo();
        Debug.WriteLine("A foo()");
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I have a website that uses different roles for the same user - all of them inherits from the same baseuser. I need to bind the controls only once on the base class.

Comment: I have tried this approach before also, it works, but the boolean have the same "true" value also later. In my case when a user call refresh to the website - it doesn't call the base control bindings (foo method) cause the boolean is already set from before. how can I reset the boolean in the end of the loop for the next time? since it is static - I cant reach it.

Comment: @kfir - you could add a public static method on the base class called `Reset`. See update.

Comment: @kfir - again, this really breaks SoS and encapsulation. The best way to do this would be to refactor your code and split the dependency you have so this is no longer necessary.

Comment: thanks, it worked - but without the static keyword. I mean : public void Reset()
    {    isFooCalled = false;    } using the static keyword makes the method unreachable from outside the class

Comment: @kfir - you can call it if it is `public static` with `Base.Reset();`

Comment: @kfir - The problem you are going to have though is that this is a web environment. This means you will have race conditions and as soon as you have 2 or more requests that come in at roughly the same time there will be problems with this solution.

Comment: @kfir - so, again, the whole design should be scraped an rethought.

Comment: I have checked it - you are right - in the case of multiple tabs - the static value will be the same for all tabs since the session is the same. I will look for better solution

Answer (score 0):

If you want to execute some logic only once then add a static constructor in the base class and move the base::foo logic to this static constructor

```
static Base()
{
   // Move the Base::foo logic here
}
```

This may not be the answer to your question but may meet your requirement.

Comment: Thanks - but the foo(bond controls) method should only be called later, not related to the construction of the classes.